# Multi table auditing stucture

Tags: sql, oracle

In this scenario I have the following tables:
HEADER_TABLE
DETAIL_TABLE_1 (FK to HEADER_TABLE)

And
HEADER_TABLE_AUDIT
DETAIL_AUDIT_TABLE_1

What I would like to do is create a single snap shot of the two tables in the audit tables when a change...um "session".. occurs. So for instance, If the header record AND 3 of 20 associated child records are updated at the same time, or "session" then the triggers on each table will only result in writing of one header audit record and 20 detail audit records (as they were before changes are applied).

I had the idea to attach a change session id that I retrieve from a sequence, and attach to all the changes being made within that session (1  header record, and 3 child records) and passed on to the audit tables. This would result in 4 trigger fires between the 2 tables, but should only write 1 set of data (header record and associated detail records). A check for the change session id in the audit tables (either header or detail) would determine whether a new set needs to be created, or just skip if it already exists (1st trigger fires, doesn't find change session id, creates audit records for all tables, next trigger fires and sees same change session id exists already so it skips adding audit records and so on).

This works ok if I am jusy updating the header record only. The trouble I am running into is when I am updating child records, how do I select the 20 detail records within the trigger on the detail table (understandably, oracle doesn't allow this)?

Of course, I am open to other ideas on doing this, as this was the best I could think of to create a snap shot of data from all involved tables prior to it being updated. I have wrestled with this one for a while so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Comment: Why do you need the whole snapshot when you can recreate them based on changes? what's the reason behind that decision?

Comment: I was hoping to get away with easily creating snapshots and then giving users the ability to review multiple versions. After thinking about it, I think I have a design idea where I can just save the values being changed, but still give them what they need. Thanks for helping me step back and take a different look!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project I'm working on with a similar requirement. Let me describe how I have done this, it could be helpful for you.
Requirement: Have a copy of the entire record whenever there is a change. Suppose our table is the EMP table from the sample data provided by oracle.

Implementation:
EMP is no longer a table, it is a view. All the data (the active version AND all the older rows are stored in a table called EMP_ALL.

EMP_ALL has a couple of additional columns:

- version_no: this is the timestamp in format YYYYMMDDHH24MISS so it is visible when the change was done.
- active_version: contains 1 for the row which is current and 0 for all the audited rows.
- emp_key: an id which is the same for each row for an employee - more about this later

EMP is a view with the definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view EMP AS 
SELECT
  <all_columns>
FROM EMP_ALL 
WHERE active_version = 1
```

There is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on EMP so whenever EMP is updated, the old row is copied into EMP_ALL (with active_version=0) and the current row is updated EMP_ALL (with active_version = 1). The reason that we update the current row is that we want to keep the primary key of the active row because that can be used for any foreign key definitions.  The foreign key needs to map to the active row, not to an archived row. The column EMP_KEY is used as an identifier for a single employee.

EMP_ALL has a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to populate the audit columns.

The same logic can be applied to any child tables. The column "version_no" will indicate when something changed and determines the order of the changes. This is very useful when constructing an audit trail.

Note: You can not use the `RETURNING INTO` clause that is used by applications (like Apex) when doing insert on the EMP view.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the a "session number" from the following:

```
select sid, serial# from v$session.
```

Use these along with current timestamp and the PK of the row being updated to generate a unique(? see not handled below) key for the AUDIT record. Write to the audit tables *only the row being updated* (update 3 of 20 details write only those 3). You can then reconstruct an "as of" version of the entire structure when ever necessary. This handles the following:

- Header updated, but no details updated.
- Detail(s) updated but not the header.
- Multiple headers updated in single statement.
- Multiple details across multiple headers updated in single statement.

What is not handled:

- Multiple updates of single row within single transaction (may need
  sequence to avoid duplicate generated key and provide proper sequencing).
- Deletes. Especially troublesome delete header.
- Inserts (if needed).